# I can make clickable country labels but get error when I click anywhere else

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to create a pop when the user clicks the country label. My code accomplishes this but if the user accidentally clicks anywhere else I get the error  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        lng: -32.87393,
        lat: 43.6439,
        zoom: 3,
        mxZoom: 7,
         
    };
    this.mapContainer = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { lng, lat, zoom , mxZoom} = this.state;
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: this.mapContainer.current,
    style: 'mapbox://styles/chriswade112358/ckpipp5el0jky18qwzep8ppyl',
    center: [lng, lat],
    zoom: zoom,
    minZoom: zoom,
    maxZoom: mxZoom,
    });

    map.on('style.load', function() {

        map.on('click', function(e) {
              const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['country-label'] });
              new mapboxgl.Popup()
                  .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
                  .setHTML('you clicked here: <br/>' + features[0].properties.name)
                  .addTo(map);
        });
      });
}
```

Comment: Not every click will return features, you’ll need to check if `features[0]` is not null before creating the popup